# Is it OK to say "I am Nathan, I am smart, I am nice" in English in answer to "Who are you?"?

Tags: responses

Is it ok to answer, "I am smart,  I am kind, and I am strong" to the question, "Who are you?"?

Comment: Not if you want to pass the Turing Test.  That's what the robot would say right before it turned off life support.

Comment: It's not usually OK to _tell_ someone that you are nice, kind etc. - you leave them to find that out from your behaviour! But this isn't really a language question.

Comment: This question can be better answered in Interpersonal Skills SE.

Comment: Me: Who are you? You: I am smart, I am kind, and I am strong! Me: Bye!

Comment: Me: **What** are you? You: I am smart, I am kind, and I am strong! Me: And boastful. Bye!

Answer (score 2):

Your response is grammatically correct English.  But it doesn't answer the question.

"Who are you?" is asking for you to identify yourself.  The reply should be "I'm Jean"  (or I'm Nathan).  It isn't asking to describe yourself.

So it is not correct to answer "I am smart (etc)" to "Who are you?"

If someone says "Tell me about yourself" you might say "I am smart..." but it sounds very arrogant.

Comment: I always found it odd that if a smart person says they're smart, it's arrogant, but if a tall person says they're tall, it's not

Comment: Height can be measured with a ruler.  You can put a number on it and everyone will agree.  Intelligence can't be measured.  Psycologists can't even decide on a defintion, much less a test (IQ tests just test how good you are at IQ tests).  And we are social animals. There is a context to being smart being judged as smart.  It is just the same as "an attractive person claiming to be attractive".  It's arrogant.